# Why can a polynomial that has only one repeated solution be factorised?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example $f(x)=2x^2+11x+12$ can be factorised as:

$$(2x-3)(x+4)$$

but $f(x)=0$ has only one solution, $x=0$. This confuses me because $(2x-3)(x+4)=0$ has two, namely $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and $x=-4$. But they are not the zero solutions to that polynomial. With what am I getting confused here?

[image]

Comment: We have $f(0)=12$. And the factorization is not right.

Comment: I don't like your image, I like [this](http://www3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP123721cic9e9gf6i165i0000180561e378ag6037?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=11&w=399.&h=188.&cdf=RangeControl) more.

Comment: The factorization if
$$
f(x) = (2 x + 3) (x + 4).
$$
Plug in $x = -3/2$ or $x = -4$ and you get $0$.

Comment: The scale of the plot is way too tiny to see stuff like the zeros there.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the factorization you put in there wasn't quite right, it should be $(2x + 3)(x+4)$.

More importantly, the polynomial does *indeed* have two zeros.  You just can't see them clearly in your plot due to the scale of the plot.

Answer (score 3):

You should zoom on your plot and you may can see that the roots of
$$f(x)=2x^2+11x+12=(2x+3)(x+4)$$
are $-\frac{3}{2}$ and $-4$

Comment: Short and simple!